# How to run Apache Spark with S3 (Minio) secured with self-signed certificate?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, minio

I installed Minio (I installed Minio in Kubernetes using [helm](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/minio)) with TLS using a self-signed certificate. Previsouly I was able to run my spark job with Minio without TLS.
Now it is not possible to conect to Minio (normal !)

Then, I created a truststore file from the tls certificate

```
keytool -import \
  -alias tls \
  -file tls.crt \
  -keystore truststore.jks \
  -storepass "$minioTruststorePass" \
  -noprompt
```

I create a Kubernetes secret with the content of the truststore and I use in the spark-defaults.conf the following option to let spark use the trustore:

```
spark.kubernetes.driver.secrets.minio-truststore-secret
```

Finally, I did all the following change in my spark-defaults.conf but same problem

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint                                      https://smart-agriculture-minio:9000
spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId                                 <s3aAccessKey>
spark.hadoop.fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey                             <s3aSecretKey>
spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl                                           org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key                                    <s3aAccessKey>
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key                                    <s3aSecretKey>
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access                             true
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl                                          org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled                        true
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions                                      -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/spark/conf/minio/truststore/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<minioTruststorePass>
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions                                   -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/spark/conf/minio/truststore/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<minioTruststorePass>
```

Have you ever faced this problem and do you have an idea to solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: No personal experience, sorry. Underneath it all the apache http client 4.4.x is being used and then to JSSE.I'd have expected those javax optuions to work. Be less ambitious: get the "hadoop fs -ls" command to work first

Comment: @Yassir you found solution to this? We have similar setup and facing similar issue.

Comment: Here is what I did in my on project https://gitlab.com/ysennoun/smart-agriculture-with-k8s/-/blob/master/deploy/platform/data-processing/spark-jobs/dockerfiles/Dockerfile-es-to-parquet#L22

Answer (score 3):

Quite late, but I got the Hadoop S3/AWS connector to work with a self-signed cert by importing it to the  default Java truststore via:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias certalias \
-noprompt -file /path/to/cert.crt \
-keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts \
-storepass changeit
```

changeit is the default Java cacerts password.

Comment: Hey @Hermann, when we providing jar from host then using this spark job is able to access data. However, if i tryinh to provide the in s3 as well it is giving me error code 400, Bad request. Any idea how to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

spark use hadoop libs, which are using aws-sdk,
so you should disable certs check.

```
com.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking=true
```

as I have understood , you would like to get answer for k8s + spark operator
just add for driver and executor this property to your yaml file

```
javaOptions: "-Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking=true"
```

fyi: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/docs/user-guide.md#specifying-extra-java-options

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/SDKGlobalConfiguration.java#L29-L34

Answer (score 0):

```
javaOptions: "-Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.disableCertChecking=true"
```

Worked for me for hive !